# Show select box options based on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a JSP page. I created some links.

```
<div align="center" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; position:absolute;left:20px; top:100px; width: 150px;">
    <br>
    <a class="applicationdata" href="#" id="1">Organization Data</a><br>
    <a class="applicationdata" href="#" id="2">Business Units</a><br>
    <a class="applicationdata" href="#" id="3">Applications</a><br>
    <a class="applicationdata" href="#" id="4">Data Entity</a><br>
    <br>
</div>
```

Similar to that I have created many links. And also I have a select box

```
<label class="control-label" for="dataloadType">Data load Type:</label>
<select id="dataloadType" name="dataloadType">
    <option value="fromDB">From Database</option>
    <option value="fromFile">From File</option>
    <option value="email">E-mail</option>
    <option value="webServices">Web Services</option>
</select>
```

What I want is, when I click on *Organization data*, the select box should display first and second options only(*from database & from file*), if I select *Business Unit*, I want to display next two options only, If I select third one, I need to display all options and if I click on last link, it should display first and third option only.
If there is only two or three links I could have used many select boxes, But I have more than 20 links. So it will be difficult to code for all that too common options.

So is there any way I can achieve this? Can someone give idea?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post ur code @ jsfiddle.net

Comment: Nothing I have tried. I don't get any idea how to do it. If it was many select boxes I could have done, But this, I don't get any idea

Comment: @swetha I have only this code, no script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show only options that are in scope you can create hidden select containing all options and option "type" stored as a class:

```
<option class="organization applications data" value="fromDB">From Database</option>
<option class="organization applications" value="fromFile">From File</option>
<option class="business applications data" value="email">E-mail</option>
<option class="business applications" value="webServices">Web Services</option>
```

you can add "type" to links by data attribute:

```
<a data-selectType="organization" class="applicationdata" href="#" id="1">Organization Data</a><br>
<a data-selectType="business" class="applicationdata" href="#" id="2">Business Units</a><br>
<a data-selectType="applications" class="applicationdata" href="#" id="3">Applications</a><br>
<a data-selectType="data" class="applicationdata" href="#" id="4">Data Entity</a>
```

and then on link click clone them to your desired select.

Example here http://jsbin.com/otocum/1/

Answer (score 1):

this may be easier than you think.

here is the working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uvwqL/2/

here is the jquery:

```
function setOptions(o1,o2,o3,o4){
        $("#o1").prop("selected", o1);
        $("#o2").prop("selected", o2);        
        $("#o3").prop("selected", o3);
        $("#o4").prop("selected", o4);
}

$().ready(function() {
    $("#1").on("click", function(){
        setOptions(true,true,false,false);
    });
    $("#2").on("click", function(){
        setOptions(false,false,true,true);
    });
    $("#3").on("click", function(){
        setOptions(true,true,true,true);        
    });
    $("#4").on("click", function(){
        setOptions(true,false,true,false);        
    });    
});
```

here is the html (i added ids to each of your options to make this easy)

```
<div align="center" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; position:absolute;left:20px; top:100px; width: 150px;">
    <br>
    <a class="applicationdata" href="#" id="1">Organization Data</a><br>
    <a class="applicationdata" href="#" id="2">Business Units</a><br>
    <a class="applicationdata" href="#" id="3">Applications</a><br>
    <a class="applicationdata" href="#" id="4">Data Entity</a><br>
    <br>
</div>

<label class="control-label" for="dataloadType">Data load Type:</label>
<select id="dataloadType" name="dataloadType" multiple>
    <option id="o1" value="fromDB">From Database</option>
    <option id="o2" value="fromFile">From File</option>
    <option id="o3" value="email">E-mail</option>
    <option id="o4" value="webServices">Web Services</option>
</select>
```